# AesCryptoServiceProvider, performance problems

Tags: c#, .net, performance

I have a two very simple methods to encrypt/decrypt a byte[] using the AesCryptoServiceProvider. But I'm very surprised about the performance of the method.

I tried to encrypt and decrypt as many bytes[] as my computer can and in the first 4 seconds I can encrypt about 2000 times, but in the next 4 seconds, about 1000, in the next four seconds, about 500... at the end i can have about 80 operations per 4 seconds. Why?

Look at the code.

```
namespace Encrypttest
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Security.Cryptography;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Globalization;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("AES provider");

            var key = GenerateKey();
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(2);
            var toStop = now.AddSeconds(120);
            long operations = 0;

            byte[] buffer = new byte[16];
            byte[] result = new byte[buffer.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
            {
                buffer[i] = 2;
            }

            for (long i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
            {
                result = Encrypt(buffer, key);
                Decrypt(result, key);
                buffer = result;
                operations++;

                if (DateTime.Now > now)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(now.ToLongTimeString() + ";" + operations + ";" + System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64);
                    operations = 0;
                    now = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(2);
                }

                if (toStop < DateTime.Now)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Encrypts the specified data.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="data">The data to encrypt</param>
        /// <param name="key">The key to encrypt data.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// The data encrypted.
        /// </returns>
        public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] data, SymmetricKey key)
        {
            if (data == null || data.Length == 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
            }

            if (key == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
            }


            using (AesCryptoServiceProvider providerInLine = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (ICryptoTransform cryptoEncryptor = providerInLine.CreateEncryptor(key.Key, key.IV))
                    {
                        using (CryptoStream writerStream = new CryptoStream(stream, cryptoEncryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                        {
                            writerStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                            writerStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                            return stream.ToArray();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Decrypts the specified data.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="data">The data to decrypt</param>
        /// <param name="key">The key to decrypt data.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// The data encrypted.
        /// </returns>
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2202:Do not dispose objects multiple times")]
        public static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] data, SymmetricKey key)
        {
            if (data == null || data.Length == 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
            }

            if (key == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
            }


            using (AesCryptoServiceProvider provider = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                using (MemoryStream memStreamEncryptData = new MemoryStream(data))
                {
                    using (ICryptoTransform cryptoDecryptor = provider.CreateDecryptor(key.Key, key.IV))
                    {
                        using (CryptoStream stream = new CryptoStream(memStreamEncryptData, cryptoDecryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                        {
                            byte[] plainTextBytes = new byte[data.Length];
                            stream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
                            return plainTextBytes;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generates a random key and initialization vector
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// The key and initialization vector.
        /// </returns>
        public static SymmetricKey GenerateKey()
        {
            using (AesCryptoServiceProvider provider = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                provider.GenerateKey();
                SymmetricKey key = new SymmetricKey(provider.Key, provider.IV);
                return key;
            }
        }
    }

    public class SymmetricKey
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The key.
        /// </summary>
        private byte[] key;

        /// <summary>
        /// The initialization vector.
        /// </summary>
        private byte[] iv;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SymmetricKey"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public SymmetricKey()
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SymmetricKey"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key">The key.</param>
        /// <param name="iv">The iv.</param>
        public SymmetricKey(byte[] key, byte[] iv)
        {
            this.Init(key, iv);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the key.
        /// </summary>
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1819:PropertiesShouldNotReturnArrays", Justification = "Byte[] is what the providers need")]
        public byte[] Key
        {
            get { return this.key; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the iv.
        /// </summary>
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1819:PropertiesShouldNotReturnArrays", Justification = "Byte[] is what the providers need")]
        public byte[] IV
        {
            get { return this.iv; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Loads the specified key and iv
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="newKey">The key.</param>
        /// <param name="newIV">The iv.</param>
        public void Init(byte[] newKey, byte[] newIV)
        {
            this.key = newKey;
            this.iv = newIV;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A compilable example wouldn't have hurt...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ciphertext is 16 bytes larger than the plaintext due to padding. Since you're using the ciphertext of of one iteration as the plaintext of the next, the length of the buffer grows linearly with the number of iterations so far. This explains the slowdown.

After 2000 iterations it needs to encrypt 30kB per iteration, after 6000 iterations it needs to encrypt 100kB per iteration...

Comment: No, that not true. buffer always is 32 bytes lenght, so encrypt always encrypt 32 bytes except the first time, that it encrypt 16 bytes

Comment: @cpsaez Print the buffer size in your printing code, and you'll see that I'm right. ` buffer = result;` is responsible, it turns the ciphertext of the previous encryption into the plaintext of the next encryption.